Can I dynamically generate a contiguous sequence of non-default-ctorable objects which can be deleted with delete[]?
Suppose I have:



Identifier
Meaning




T
a non-default-constructible class


gen
a function returning a T


n
a positive size_t value



Now, I want to generate n T-objects, using gen, consecutively on the heap - but such that I can later destruct all of them and free the memory using delete[] on the address of the first of them.
If T were default-constructible, then this is trivial:
T* my_t_objects = new T[n];

after which I can delete[] my_t_objects and Bob's my uncle. But - array-new won't work when I can't default-construct. Is there some other way to achieve the same effect...

when gen takes no parameters, i.e. T gen()?
when gen takes an index, i.e. T gen(size_t) (in which case I can't make the same call for all elements)?

My intuitive idea is to allocate the memory for the n objects, and then call placement-new n times with increasing indices; but if I do that, I'm somewhat doubtful that a delete[] on the T * pointer I get from the allocation would actually do what's necessary.

Notes:

No, I don't want to use an std::vector<T> and std::generate, thank you :-)
If it helps, gen() can be assumed to be noexcept.
Assume no ctor of T is public, and gen is a friend.
A solution valid only in C++20 or later (due to considerations mentioned here) is fine, although I'd appreciate not relying on that, at least for practical purposes.


Why don't you want to use std::vector?  It's built to do these types of things

@NathanOliver: 1. std::vector has semantics I can't tolerate; mainly, resizing and reserving. 2. I want to know if this is something placement-new can be used for or not. 3. The libdtdc++ implementation of std::vector is 2145-lines long.

Do you control T? If so, you can redefine what delete[] my_t_objects means by replacing destroying-delete functions and then do whatever you need to destroy and deallocate.

But if this a practical question and std::vector is truly somehow unsuitable (doubtful) you'd be better off rolling your own dynamic array type which manages the allocation and construction separately instead of trying to hack together a pointer that can be delete[]ed.

As far as I am aware if you T* ptr = new T[size];, then you must delete ptr[]; even if you treat ptr as a U*. Could you wrap a vector in your own wrapper so you can prevent the interface about it that you don't like?

@yurikilochek: I need delete[] to act as usual, usually, but not in this particular case.

@yurikilochek: Re rolling my own: But then, this dynamic array type would only be constructible this way, while I want it to also be constructible with a simple new[] for default-constructible T's.

@NathanOliver: I could wrap a vector, yes. But that doesn't tell me how to do what I asked about, just how to circumvent doing it.

I want it to also be constructible with a simple new[] for default-constructible T's. Why? What's the issue with  doing it using a constructor of your custom dynamic array type?

@yurikilochek: Because I want to be either do construction on my own or take memory allocated by others. If I can't reasonably enforce a "deletable by delete[]" requirement, I will need to also take a deleter.

Warning: This relies on implementation details and has undefined behavior !

I hope that noone uses this without understanding that by doing so, the whole program will have undefined behavior. To make sure that the program actually does what you want it to do and only that, the assembly code after compiling this will have to be investigated - every time it's recompiled.

You could create a default-constructible class that inherits from your non-default constructible type and instantiate that instead:
template <class T, T(*generator)()>
T* new_with_generator(std::size_t size) {
    struct default_constructible : T {
        // use the generator for T:
        default_constructible() : T(generator()) {}
    };

    static_assert(sizeof(default_constructible) == sizeof(T));
    static_assert(alignof(default_constructible) == alignof(T));

    return new default_constructible[size];
}

Then using it:
struct foo {        // a non-default constructible class
    foo() = delete;
    foo(int X) : m_str(std::to_string(X)) {}

    std::string m_str;
};

int main(int argc, char**) {
    size_t elems = static_cast<size_t>(argc + 10);

    foo* foos = new_with_generator<foo, []{
        static int x = 0;
        return foo(++x);
    }>(elems);

    // do stuff ...

    // UB: deleting through a base class pointer with a non-virtual destructor:
    delete[] foos;
}

Demo

Again: Although this currently works in the four major implementations, it has undefined behavior since it uses delete[] through a base class pointer with a non-virtual destructor.

When the standard fails to define the behavior of things like delete[], then answers to my question easily veer into the domain of undefined behavior. +1 for the idea, and it's probably safe in practice despite formally being UB - although I would obviously prefer a defined-behavior solution.

@einpoklum I just thought about if the non-default constructible is final and came up with this which also is not detected by the sanitizers but "feels" even more UB, if there is such a thing as more or less UB :-)

If you don't mind a massive amount of functions being instantiated, you could convert the runtime value size to a constant expression and then new[]{...} as usual. This will have a runtime cost since it requires to check the condition a number of times to find the correct instantiation of the function template - so it's not something that would be useful where speed matters.
This example supports arrays up to size 1024 but it's easily extendible at the expense of longer compilation times. Compiling one usage of this monster for the range [1, 1024] takes ~6.5 minutes on my machine.
First a generic binary search function to convert a runtime value to a compiletime constant:
namespace detail {
template<class T, T L, T H, class F>
decltype(auto) binsearch(T value, F&& func) {
    // binary search for the compiletime constant
    if constexpr(L != H) {
        if(value > (L + H) / 2)
            return binsearch<T, (L + H) / 2 + 1, H>(value, std::forward<F>(func));
        return binsearch<T, L, (L + H) / 2>(value, std::forward<F>(func));
    } else {
        // here L == value, so call the supplied function:
        return func(std::integral_constant<T, L>{});
    }
}
} // namespace detail

// A function to convert a runtime value, value, to a compiletime
// constant and call a function taking an integral_constant<T, value>:
template<class T, T L, T H, class F>
decltype(auto) runtime_to_compiletime(T value, F&& func) {
    if(value < L || value > H)
        throw std::length_error("value " + std::to_string(value) +
                                " not in range [" + std::to_string(L) + ", " +
                                std::to_string(H) + "]");

    return detail::binsearch<T, L, H>(value, std::forward<F>(func));
}

This can then be used by your new-like function that takes a runtime value and a generator:
constexpr std::size_t max_array_size = 1024;

template<class T, class G>
T* new_plus(std::size_t size, G&& gen) {
    // search in the range [1, max_array_size]:
    return runtime_to_compiletime<std::size_t, 1, max_array_size>( size,
        // The function to execute once the compile time constant, N, has been
        // found:
        [&gen]<std::size_t N>(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>) {
            return [&gen]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
                // create the array of non-default constructibles:
                return new T[N]{((void)I, gen())...};
            }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
        });
}

template<class T, class G>
std::unique_ptr<T[]> make_unique_array(std::size_t size, G&& gen) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T[]>(new_plus<T>(size, std::forward<G>(gen)));
}

Demo (with the range [1, 128] to not timeout while compiling)

I need this to work for large values of size. But in limited cases something like this should work.

@einpoklum I see. You could make it capable handling large sizes too. The only problem would be if it's something that is going to be executed often since the binary search for the right N will take some time. Here's a more generic version for sizes up to 1048576 elements. It'll take some time to compile that I guess :-)

@einpoklum It's hard to make a version that actually compiles in reasonable time. This version for arrays up to 1024 elements is faster than the above but still takes 2min 20sec for gcc to compile and 13 seconds for clang++ on my computer. Of course, if you know anything about the size range, you can limit the binary search to that range and save both compilation time and execution time.

This is intended for a super-generic general-purpose'ish container which can't restrict the size at all. The thing about this container is that it's supposed to play nice both with T*'s which originate in new T[n] calls, and with T*'s which result in non-array new followed by placements.

@einpoklum Ah, ok. Does the container have to expose its inner workings to the user? If it's responsible for both creating and deleting the elements, making such a container is rather straight forward.

The container is not responsible for creating the elements (except through an independent "maker" function; but it is responsible for destroying them and de-allocating the space they use, since it is owning. Basically it's like a unique_ptr which is also a span.

@einpoklum Ok. It would probably be easier if the container is responsible for both the creation and destruction. Here's an example of what I was thinking of

It would be easier for the container author but not for the user. Part of the motivation is taking raw pointers to allocated memory and wrapping them in an owning container.

@einpoklum Tricky. I don't see any way other than what I put in the answer - and that will take a very long time to compile (but is not terrible in runtime).

Asked this to support my efforts.

@einpoklum I couldn't let this go since it's a very interesting problem and I made an updated, more generic, version that compiles faster than the old one (allowing for bigger ranges). I think this is the only way to get a delete[]able pointer to an array of non-default constructibles, but if you find another way, please ping me here because I'd really like to know how too.

@einpoklum If you would be willing to live with UB, I got this. It's accepted by the major compilers and the sanitizers don't detect/react on the UB. It's relying on implementation details which is fragile to say the least.

Make that another answer?

@einpoklum Done. Oh, I will get so much flak for this answer I think :-)
